# Team Foundation Server Schedule trigger only if another build is not failing

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Currently I have a canary build that builds code and runs tests, but doesn't "publish" anything.  It is just a way to make sure that a checkin doesn't break the build.

I have a second build that is the "Publish" build that builds and publishes (at this point it does not do tests because it assumes that the canary build validated tests).  This publish build runs every night IF there are changesets in the queue. But I'd like to prevent the publish build from running if the last canary build broke as well.  How can I do that?

Publish build:

1. Schedule build at 1am and run:

   a. IF there are changesets in the queue AND

   b. IF the last Canary build succeeded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you thought about changing your 'canary' build to a gated check-in, which will prevent any code from getting into the code base unless the build succeeds.

Then, set your nightly build as a schedule (which I imagine you already have), but just uncheck "Build even if nothing has changed"

Comment: I will try this out and that would be ideal, both to solve my issue and plain and simple prevent breaking code from getting in the builds.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to check another build fails or not in the default process template unless you create a custom template like this one http://blog.stangroome.com/2011/09/06/queue-another-team-build-when-one-team-build-succeeds/

Why don't you include the unit tests in the publish build, what ever the size of the change set I guess the unit test is going to run once and i guess it's not going to take more time. So you can change the flow

Publish build:

Schedule build at 1am and run:

a. IF there are changesets in the queue AND

b. IF the build succeeds and unit test passes.

Answer (score 0):

Is your build process too time consuming? If not why not do a build right before publishing? There by you dont have to check the CI build output?

It's easy and you dont need any extra effort :)

Comment: I am not done converting my TeamCity build process to TFS, so I am not sure how long the PROD build will take.  I hope to have the Canary build run as fast as possible so that it will fail fast.  Canary at the moment takes 10 minutes.

Comment: I think 10 minutes is fast enough. In that case, I think its better to do a build right before publishing :) so that you dont have to write code to check status of the canary build. This would be the easiest and most productive in my opinion.

Comment: My Prod build does a build before publishing.  But I don't want to publish every time someone checks something in.  The canary build builds after every checkin and confirms that you didn't break the build. I am going with @pm_2 suggestion for now.